# magento2 getcustomer email

Tags: magento2.3

I want to get email from customer session login. But i have problem

```
public function execute()
{
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
    $email = $customerSession->getEmail();
    echo $email;exit;

    if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $resultRedirect->setUrl('/customer/account/login');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: Please replace $email = $customerSession->getEmail(); to $email = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail(); and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types :-

You want to using `Object Manager` try this code :-

```
<?php
    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
    $storeManager  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $storeID       = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId(); 
    $storeName     = $storeManager->getStore()->getName();
?>

<?php
    $customerSession = $om->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
    if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail(); // get Email
    }
?>
```

**Second:-**

You need to inject `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession`, class to get customer ID from customer session. Try this code.
    protected $_customerSession;

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    ...
}

public function getCustomer()
{
    echo $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId(); //Print current customer ID

    $customerData = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer(); 
    print_r($customerData->getData()); //Print current Customer Data
    echo 'Customer Id: ' . $customerData->getId() . '<br/>';
    echo 'Customer Name: ' . $customerData->getName() . '<br/>';
    echo 'Customer Email: ' . $customerData->getEmail() . '<br/>';
    echo 'Customer Group Id: ' . $customerData->getGroupId() . '<br/>';
}
```

**NOTE:** You only get customer id if customer logged in and customer session initialized

Hope this help you

Thanks ...